# Not able to add data in firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Even if the rules are set to true and i am writing a simple code to add data using user input, I am not able to add data and even not able to create a child node manually.

The toast runs successfully but data is not entered and it has got no errors.

[image: code in android studio]

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.